# Render an object multiple times a frame using different textures. What's more performant? Multiple Materials or calling SetTexture multiple times?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I need to render an object multiple times a frame using different textures. I was wondering about the most performant way to do so. My first approach was to have one Material and in OnRenderImage() call SetTexture() on it for the given number of textures I have. Now I'm wondering if it would be a noticeable improvement if I set up one Material per Texture in Start() and change between Materials in OnRenderImage(). Then I wouldn't need the SetTexture() call. But I can't find what SetTexture() actually does. Does it just set a flag or does it copy or upload the texture somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

From working with low-end devices extensively, performance comes from batching. It's hard to pin point what would improve performance in your context w/o a clear understanding of the scope:

- How many objects
- How many images
- Target platform
- Are the images packaged or external at runtime
- ...

But as a general rule you want to use least amount of materials and individual textures possible. If pre-processing is an option, I would recommend creating spritesheets with as many images as possible on a single image. Then using UV offsetting you can show multiple images on multiple objects for 1 draw call.

I have used extensively a solution called [TexturePacker](https://www.codeandweb.com/texturepacker) which supports Unity. It's not cheap, there's an app to buy plus a plugin for Unity but it saves time, and draw calls, in the end.

Things like packing hundreds of images into a few 4k textures and down to 3 or 4 draw calls vs 100s before.

That might not be a solution in your case, but the concept is still valid.

Also unity prefabs will not save Draw Calls, but reduce memory usage.

hth.

J.

Comment: One object, less than 10 (large!) textures, any platform, textures are in separate Texture variables already. Was more interested in the direct comparison between having multiple materials with textures pre set or one material and changing that materials texture multiple times a frame. I make several draw calls a frame either way. Nice general summary though.

Comment: Yea, when you modify a material's texture at runtime you break the batching and add draw calls. It might still be worth batching into spritesheets, tho :)

Comment: For my application I have to perform one draw call per texture anyway. I do it myself using Graphics.Blit, so I don't think there would be any difference between the two options in that regard. Spritesheets aren't an option for me.